# How this happens in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I created a function showed below, and if called `print(sum_num(1,2))` it will show up 2 output which are `3` and `None`. As long as I removed `print`, it would go right. Can anyone explain why it will work like this? Thank you so much!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lrGX.png)

Comment: As your are a new contributor, and as a side note, [you should not post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 2):

Add `return` statement to your function.

You are only printing the value in function so it will first print 3 which is 1+2
but it returns `None` That's where your 2nd output comes from.

Use below code:

```
def sum_num(a,b):
    # print(a+b)
    return a+b

print(sum_num(1,2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried the code but it will print out "3" two times.

Comment: Ok. Appreciate it